# WPF - How to point a setter at a child object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following xaml :

```
<Canvas Name="MainCanvas" Style="{StaticResource MainCanvasStyle}">
    <ListView Name="MainListView" Style="{StaticResource MainListViewStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="dnd">
                        <Setter TargetName="CanvasItem" Property="Canvas.Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Canvas Name="CanvasItem" Height="30" Width="222" Margin="10,5,10,5">
                    <Canvas.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Orange"/>
                            <GradientStop Offset="1"  Color="{Binding Background, ElementName=CanvasItem}"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Canvas.Background>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" TextAlignment="Justify" FontSize="18" Width="150" Canvas.Top="2" Canvas.Left="10" FontWeight="Thin"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="18" Width="50" Canvas.Top="2" Canvas.Right="5" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Canvas>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the second color of LinearGradientBrush in CanvasItems change depending on the current value of Items.Status.

I'd like to acomplish that by **targeting the Colors inside LinearGradientBrush in CanvasItem in my setter**. How could that be done?
If there are better ways of doing this then I'm open to suggestions.

Another idea I had was to handle in my ViewModel, but I'm not sure if binding them to this ListView would be possible, as my ItemsSource is already set to Items, and I don't want to modify the class that holds those.

/// While the question remains unanswered, I managed to get this to work like described by changing the Setter part to :

```
<Setter TargetName="CanvasItem" Property="Canvas.Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Orange"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Red"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I also deleted the part with Canvas.Background in CanvasItem.

This requires me to copy and paste that snippet into every single setter which isn't as comfortable as referencing the exact color in the setter (the one in second GradientStop). There are about ten different color setters in my code so you can imagine how clumsy that looks like.

Comment: Not sure what you really intend here but background is  a brush and color is a color. Different types.. And of course you're trying to bind to the very thing you're setting. Which is also going to be a problem. And then you're also trying to set that background again but you have a value set on it. What end result do you want to achieve?

Comment: The problem isn't with colors not changing, it's just that they get overriden. Currently setter doesn't work like intended - it's bound to the overall color of Canvas.Background, but I'd like to bind it to Canvas.Background.LinearGradientBrush.(second)GradientStop.Color. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: The idea was to first set the background with a setter, then set the background again, but this time setting the background to a LinearGradientBrush where first color with offset 0 would always be orange and the second with offset 1 would be the current color. That doesn't work though, I get a solid color - the one set by the setter, not the one set by the part with <LinearGradientBrush>.

Comment: I'm still confused but you can define a color as a resource or name a color and bind another to it or you can use path syntax to find the canvas, get the gradient and then reference the color from the gradientstop by index.

Comment: If I bind the color in LinearGradientBrush to a resource color and then bind to it, wouldn't it result in having the same color on each ListViewItem's Canvas?

Comment: Also if you could show how to use path syntax to find the canvas, that would be great. I can't really picture it.

Comment: It does seem simplier to just name the color and then reference it in the setter, but it doesn't seem like I can name colors in LinearGradientBrush.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...you can't bind the `Color` of a `GradientStop` to the same `LinearGradientBrush` that the `GradientStop` belongs to if that's what you are trying to do.

You could bind to another property though. You could either use the `Tag` property or define your own attached `Brush` property:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Canvas Name="CanvasItem" Height="30" Width="222" Margin="10,5,10,5">
        <!-- default value -->
        <Canvas.Tag>
            <SolidColorBrush>Green</SolidColorBrush>
        </Canvas.Tag>
        <Canvas.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Orange"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1"  Color="{Binding Tag.Color, ElementName=CanvasItem}"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
        <TextBlock Text="Number" TextAlignment="Justify" FontSize="18" Width="150" Canvas.Top="2" Canvas.Left="10" FontWeight="Thin"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Status" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="18" Width="50" Canvas.Top="2" Canvas.Right="5" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
    </Canvas>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="dnd">
            <Setter TargetName="CanvasItem" Property="Tag">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>Orange</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow what your intention is here so I don't know whether this is a good idea or not.
But you seem to want to do it so...
You can name a colour in a gradientstop:

```
<LinearGradientBrush>
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Orange"/>
    <GradientStop Offset="1">
        <GradientStop.Color x:Name="MyColour">Red</GradientStop.Color>
    </GradientStop>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Maybe that lineargradient could be a resource or use a dynamicresource colour and you change that out using a trigger if this is used in numerous placed.

Path syntax is really fiddly to do manually and some prefer to use blend for that sort of thing. Far less headaches.  As I said, I don't really follow what you want to do here so I don't know what should be set by what from where.
Here's an example of what one looks like though:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
```

Which is referencing the rotatetransform in this:

```
<ContentControl.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform/>
        <SkewTransform/>
        <RotateTransform/>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </TransformGroup>
</ContentControl.RenderTransform>
```